# QT programming: eclipse auto-complete on mac won't work

Tags: eclipse, macos, qt

I have been struggling to enable autocompletion on Eclipse (mac) for Qt classes.
I added /Library/Frameworks/QtCore (and QtGui) to the C++ Path and Symbols tab on the preferences dialog but for some reason although it can find the class names it refuses to autocomplete the class methods and member attributes. Tried to use both INCLUDE and LIBRARY PATHS with no luck.

In my last attempt I pointed the includes to Linux libraries but it didn't work out either.

Has anyone faced the same issue?  I have spent over two weeks trying to get this going but I just can't figure out what is wrong there.

I'm using Qt 4.6.3 Cocoa, Eclipse Galileo on Snow Leopard.

I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also struggle with the autocompletion with Eclipse Helios and Qt 4.7.2 on Snow Leopard. I am sure that it worked with older version of Qt and Eclipse.

I looked into some of the Qt header files and it seems that problem is that there are used some strange macros (e.g. between class and the class name). It would not surprise me if that breaks the Eclipse indexer.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, I guess it does break the indexer.

The workaround for me was downloading a complete source of the QT lib, extract it somewhere and add that to the eclipse include path. It obviously won't pick them up to compile nor anything but at least the auto-completion works ok.